# running Postgis Database in Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

i am trying to run my Postgis Database in a Docker Container. Therefore i dumped my database and created a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mdillon/postgis
COPY z_myDump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I use the mdillon postgis as base image (Postgis Extensions are already included) and copy my dump. The container disappears after a few seconds with the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/z_myDump.sql
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/z_myDump.sql: Permission denied
```

any idea?

Comment: It might sound like a soft ball, but are you sure that the current user has permission to access the file `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/z_myDump.sql`?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263551/docker-postgis-sql-files-not-loading-into-database-at-build/285983#285983 it should work :)

Comment: If it works, consider answering and closing the question :-)

Comment: it doenst work for me but in the topic above it works without permission issues :/ that's why i posted this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing permissions of the .sql file before building the image did the job ... my bad